# Expanding the width of CTreeCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a Dialog with a CTreeCtrl and CListCtrl. I want to give user the flexibility of expanding the width of the CTreeCtrl after the dialog opens, based on which i would like to resize my CListCtrl.

How to enable this option ?

Comment: Use a [CSplitterWnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xttbe5t.aspx). Details on how to use are documented under [TN029: Splitter Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/969ca366.aspx).

Comment: You should elaborate your question, maybe with an image, it's hard to understand what you want.

Comment: Are you talking about re-sizing the controls while the dialog is re-sized?

Comment: No, The Width of the dialog remains same, If the CTreeCtrl's width is changed i.e. expanded, the CListCtrl's width should shrink. I dont know how the control's width can be changed after the dialog opens.